# Nuget.exe fails with "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http...'

Tags: nuget

I am trying to run "nuget restore" on a server that does not have a Visual Studio installation. But nuget.exe fails immediately. What else needs to be installed for NuGet to run?

> C:\Users\kevin>nuget help
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What .NET framework versions does your server have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue as well. Newer versions of [NuGet requires .NET 4.5](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-faq). installing [.NET 4.5.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642) resolved the issue for me.